# Implement function call (grouped running totals) in query

Tags: function, powerquery, m

I have a function called *fxGroupedRunningTotal* (fxGRT) and a query (Totals). I want to call fxGRT within Totals, so that I get a column that shows the grouped running totals. I have only managed to test the fxGRT by importing the Totals query.

*Query that uses Totals and calls fxGRT (built for testing the function):*

```
let
    Source = Totals,
    BufferedValues = List.Buffer(Source[PD]),
    BufferedMaterials = List.Buffer(Source[Material]),

    RT = Table.FromColumns(
    {
      Source[Material], Source[Date], Source[PD], 
      fxGroupedRunningTotal(BufferedValues, BufferedMaterials)
    },
    {
      "Material",
      "Date",
      "PD",
      "Running Total"
    })
in
    RT
```

*fxGroupedRunningTotals:*

```
(values as list, grouping as list) as list =>

let
    GRTList = List.Generate
    (
        ()=> [ GRT = values{0}, i = 0 ],

        each [i] < List.Count(values),

        each try if grouping{[i]} = grouping{[i] + 1}
                 then [GRT = [GRT] + values {[i] + 1}, i = [i] + 1]
                 else [GRT = values{[i] + 1}, i = [i] + 1]

            otherwise [i = [i] + 1]
    ,
        each [GRT]
    )
in
    GRTList
```

*Totals:*

```
let
    Källa = Table.NestedJoin(Cohv,{"Prod MDate"},Resb,{"Del Mdate"},"Resb",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanderad Resb" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Källa, "Resb", {"Del Material", "Del Date", "Del Qty", "Del Mdate"}, {"Del Material", "Del Date", "Del Qty", "Del Mdate"}),
    #"PD Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanderad Resb", "PD Date", each if [Prod Date] = null then [Del Date] else [Prod Date]),
    #"PD Material" = Table.AddColumn(#"PD Date", "PD Material", each if [Material Number] = null then [Del Material] else [Material Number]),
    #"PD Mdate" = Table.AddColumn(#"PD Material", "PD Mdate", each [PD Material] & "." & Date.ToText([PD Date])),
    #"Borttagna kolumner" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"PD Mdate",{"Prod Date", "Prod MDate", "Del Date", "Del Mdate"}),
    #"Ändrad typ1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Borttagna kolumner",{{"PD Date", type date}}),
    #"Ihopslagna frågor" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Ändrad typ1",{"PD Material"},Matmas,{"Material"},"Matmas",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanderad Matmas" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Ihopslagna frågor", "Matmas", {"Material", "Material Description", "MRP Controller", "Safety stock", "Minimum Lot Size", "In Stock"}, {"Material", "Material Description", "MRP Controller", "Safety stock", "Minimum Lot Size", "In Stock"}),
    #"Omdöpta kolumner" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanderad Matmas",{{"Material", "M Material"}}),
    #"Lägg till egen" = Table.AddColumn(#"Omdöpta kolumner", "Material", each if [PD Material] = null then [M Material]else [PD Material]),
    #"Borttagna kolumner1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Lägg till egen",{"Material Number", "Del Material", "PD Material", "M Material"}),
    #"Lägg till egen1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Borttagna kolumner1", "Date", each if [PD Date] = null then DateTime.LocalNow() else [PD Date]),
    #"Borttagna kolumner2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Lägg till egen1",{"PD Date"}),
    #"Lägg till egen2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Borttagna kolumner2", "Date in stock", each if [Date] = DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) then [In Stock] else null),
    #"Borttagna kolumner3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Lägg till egen2",{"Date in stock"}),
    #"Ändrad typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Borttagna kolumner3",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Ersatt värde" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Ändrad typ",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Prod Qty"}),
    #"Ersatt värde1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Ersatt värde",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Del Qty"}),
    #"Ihopslagna frågor1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Ersatt värde1",{"Date"},Dates,{"Date"},"Dates",JoinKind.RightOuter),
    #"Expanderad Dates" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Ihopslagna frågor1", "Dates", {"Current Date"}, {"Current Date"}),
    #"Omdöpta kolumner1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanderad Dates",{{"Date", "D Date"}}),
    Date = Table.AddColumn(#"Omdöpta kolumner1", "Date", each if [D Date] is null then DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) else [D Date]),
    PD = Table.AddColumn(Date, "PD", each if [Current Date] = "Yes" then [In Stock]+[Prod Qty]-[Del Qty] else [Prod Qty]-[Del Qty])
in
    PD
```

So how do I implement this function into a new column in my Totals? My attempts keep failing. Do I have to make a reference to Totals in order to make this work? It feels so wrong, since that would double the work load (?) with the data. I would like it to be as quick as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the previous step as a table. Thus your query can be written

```
let
    [...all your previous steps...]
    PD = Table.AddColumn(Date, "PD", each if [Current Date] = "Yes" then [In Stock]+[Prod Qty]-[Del Qty] else [Prod Qty]-[Del Qty]),
    RT =
        Table.FromColumns(
            List.Combine({Table.ToColumns(PD), {fxGroupedRunningTotals(PD[Material], PD[PD])}}),
            List.Combine({Table.ColumnNames(PD), {"Running Total"}})
        )
in
    RT
```

This converts the table to a list of columns, adds on the new running total column (calling the function you've defined on specific columns of the table from the previous step `PD`), and then glues those columns back together with a similar method to preserve the column names and add a new one.