# How to do a grouped running total with Power Query in Excel?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

My question or rather problem, doesn't fall to far from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65337362/implement-function-call-grouped-running-totals-in-query).
I've checked these sources to get to where I am with the code below;

[link 1](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/quickly-create-running-totals-in-power-query#comments)
[link 2](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/grouped-running-totals-in-power-query)

```
let
    Source = Table.Combine({CITIBank_USDChecking, QNBFinansbank_TRYMevduat}),
    #"Sort Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Add Custom ""Num"" Col" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sort Rows", "Num", each null),
    #"Add Custom ""Payee"" Col" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Custom ""Num"" Col", "Payee", each null),
    #"Add Custom ""Tag"" Col" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Custom ""Payee"" Col", "Tag", each null),
    #"Add Custom ""Category"" Col" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Custom ""Tag"" Col", "Category", each null),
    #"Reorder Cols" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Add Custom ""Category"" Col",{"Account", "Currency", "Date", "Num", "Payee", "Description", "Tag", "Category", "Clr", "Debit", "Credit"}),
     BufferValues = List.Buffer(#"Reorder Cols"[Debit]),
     BufferGroup = List.Buffer(#"Reorder Cols"[Account]),
     runTotal = Table.FromList ( 
        fxGroupedRunningTotal (BufferValues , BufferGroup) , Splitter.SplitByNothing() , {"runningDebit"}
    ),
     combineColumns = List.Combine (
        { Table.ToColumns (#"Reorder Cols") , Table.ToColumns(runTotal) }
    ),

    #"Convert to Table" = Table.FromColumns (
        combineColumns , List.Combine ( { Table.ColumnNames(#"Reorder Cols") , {"runningDebit"} } )
    ),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Convert to Table",{"runningDebit"}) 
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

The issue with doing grouped running totals -in my case- is the resetting that occurs once the list hits a value of 0. I don't know how to get around this issue at this point. Basically, I'm trying to get a running total of debits by account, where the debit is a list of decimal numbers and 0 at times. Maybe @alexis-olson can chime in...

[image: running debit total per account resets at 0]

Answer (score 0):

This would be the running group sum of Debits based on the sample starting image

Basically, you add an index

Compare the Account to the Account in the row below.  If they dont match, copy over the index

Fill upwards. You now have unique groupings for Account

Add a formula for running sum based on that grouping

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try if [Account] =  #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Account] then null else [Index] otherwise [Index]),
#"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Up","runningDebit",(i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Up", each [Custom] = i[Custom] and [Index]<=i[Index]) [Debit]), type number)
in #"Added Custom2"
```

Comment: thanks for the proposition, sincerely, but I think this method will get taxing over greater number of rows and I would rather implement a solution with buffer lists as outlined over here;
https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/grouped-running-totals-in-power-query